# Cannot scroll code block sideways while typing a comment

Tags: bug, ios-app, scrolling

The title explains itself. When I'm typing a comment and trying to scroll through the question, I can scroll up and down, but not left and right to see the remaining parts of a code block. This doesn't happen when I swipe the comments box down, hiding the keyboard.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)